# Xfce Panels - Change autohide delay?

Tags: xfce, autohide, xfce-panel

I'm trying to set a panel up for a small touch screen and I have a shortcut which toggles autohide, enabling autohide makes it appear, but on disabling autohide there's a short delay which is annoying.

Using Xfce4 panels, there is no way I can find within the GUI of changing the autohide delay. Are there any configuration files etc I could edit to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of Googling returns this:

> Add this to ~/.gtkrc-2.0.
>
> ```
>  style "xfce-panel-window-style"
>  {
>    # Time in miliseconds before the panel will unhide on an enter event
>    XfcePanelWindow::popup-delay = 225
>
>    # Time in miliseconds before the panel will hide on a leave event
>    XfcePanelWindow::popdown-delay = 350
>  }
>  class "XfcePanelWindow" style "xfce-panel-window-style"
> ```

Sources: [Xfce Docs: Theming](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/theming), [ArchLinux Wiki: Xfce#Panel Autohide Delay](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce#Panel_autohide_delay)

Comment: I've just tried this but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Is it possible that this would only for on ArchLinux?

Comment: Nope, it's on docs.xfce.org which does not belong to Arch

Comment: Ok, just tried it on my desktop and it's working, probably just copied it wrong or something. Thanks.

Comment: This appears to have no effect if you enter 0, but 1 is close enough, and that works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Add to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` the following:

```
#XfcePanelWindow {
   -XfcePanelWindow-popup-delay: 500;
   -XfcePanelWindow-popdown-delay: 250;
}
```

If it doesn't work after logging out, you may need to clear the cache: `rm -rf ~/.cache`

An alternative (also permanent) solution:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/popup-speed -t int -s 500 --create
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/popdown-speed -t int -s 250 --create
```

where `panel-0` is the name of the panel (see `xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels -l`). These later settings are stored in `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml`