# How to remove xfce-panel popup/popdown delay if select autohide allways?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, panel, autohide

I use XUbuntu 21.04 - before this I used XUbuntu 20.04

The Auto-Hide does not work any more as expected. There is a delay between hidden and unhidden. This is very annoying.

In the XFCE-panel-propterties I select the Auto-hide Mode: Always

But with the Always-Mode I have a delay from more than 2 seconds!
In the intelligent-Mode there is no recognizable delay.

How can I change the Auto-hide-delay to zero?

I have tried this:
[Xfce Panels - Change autohide delay?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310762/xfce-panels-change-autohide-delay)
But it does not do anything.

Comment: Maybe try setting `xfconf-query -n -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-2/popdown-speed -t int -s 0`  Source:  https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/preferences?s[]=autohide

Comment: Maybe set inactive opacity to 0? Should have a similar effect.

Comment: @Terrance - It does not work, I have still two seconds delay.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - This is not useful for me, because it is still there and then I would click on a Icon in the Panel I can not see.

Comment: Hmmmm, I have actually tried duplicating your 2 second delay and no matter what I set that popdown-speed to makes no difference.  My bar pops down as soon as I mouse over it.  Sounds to me like you have a bug.  I would file it as a bug `ubuntu-bug xfce4-panel`

Comment: I have installed XUbuntu 21.04 on a Laptop and a Desktop-PC. I changed the original settings of the panel to "hide always" and there I get the 2 seconds delay in the hide-process. If I set it to "hide intelligent", then there is nearly no delay, only the animation-time for up and down. It looks like I set only the animation-time, but there is an additional time for waiting. But I could not identify where this setting is or where I could find it.

Comment: @Terrance - If you would start the actual Live-image of XUbuntu (in a virtual machine or over a USB-Stick at your PC), then you can start the Live-System and change the Panel-Settings to the "hide always"-Mode. There you can see the 2 second delay. In the source of XFCE I have seen the variable "autohide_timeout_id".  [link]https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/-/blob/master/panel/panel-window.c[/link]

Comment: However, I did recently create a `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file and followed what they had at https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=14676 but I did end up changing both the 400 and 2500 to 0 and now it hides and unhides very instantly.  With the 400 and 2500 numbers it took the bar about 2.5 seconds to hide and .4 of a second to show up.

Comment: @Terrance - This is working very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=14676 create a new file of `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and add the following lines to it.

```
#XfcePanelWindow {
   -XfcePanelWindow-popup-delay: 0;
   -XfcePanelWindow-popdown-delay: 0;
}
```

with above if you want to add a delay just remember that it is done in milliseconds, so if you want a 2 second delay the number would be 2000.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Type `killall xfce4-panel; xfce4-panel &` on a terminal to reload panels and those changes take effect.